# Outline view plugin for shells scripts in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, shell, plugins

Is there any Eclipse Indigo plugin (or an easy way to build one) that can display a good outline view for shell scripts ?
I tried ShellEd but the outline view displayed more than only the functions list (like all the `if`s...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Eclipse Colorer](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipsecolorer) made the trick.